# Angular getting error 401 when trying to access external API with bearer token

Tags: javascript, angular, api, bearer-token

Hi i try to have an access to an external API and getting 401 or 403 error : it's driving me nuts !

The APIs are accessible there : https://www.emploi-store-dev.fr/
There's a lot of datas available and it's just impossible to have an access to any of them.
Sorry for the dirty code but working on it for two days now and the primary goal is to have a working app :p

API doc is here : https://www.emploi-store-dev.fr/portail-developpeur-cms/home/catalogue-des-api/documentation-des-api/api/api-offres-demploi-v2/rechercher-par-criteres.html (in french sorry).

Component.html :

```
<br>
<button (click)="getToken()">Get token !</button>
<br>
```

Component.ts :

```
  getToken() {
  
if (this.postService.getNews()) {

    this.postService.getNews().subscribe((data)=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.token = data.access_token;
      console.log(this.token);
     
      this.postService.getNews2(this.token).subscribe((data:Response)=>{
        console.log(data.headers);
  
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Service.ts :

```
    getNews() : Observable<any> {



      let url = 'http://localhost:4200/api/connexion/oauth2/access_token?realm=%2Fpartenaire';
      
      const opts = {

        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        })
      };

      const body = new HttpParams()
        .set('grant_type', 'client_credentials')
        .set('client_id', 'PAR_monpetitstage_f87943ec478b0bfe5f7b287c8928ace6925e2f40160700d80703dbad36316b2b')
        .set('client_secret', '6367476c8fbb3aa609377ce36930e44bb35fc1c04422362b3635176cf30f48bb')
        .set('scope', 'api_offresdemploiv2');


      return this.httpClient.post(url, body, opts);    
    }

    getNews2(token) {
     
      /*
            let url = 'http://localhost:4200/get/partenaire/offresdemploi/v2/offres/search?qualification=0&motsCles=informatique&commune=51069,76322,46083,12172,28117&origineOffre=2';
            */
  
            const url = 'https://api.emploi-store.fr/partenaire/offresdemploi/v2/offres/search';

            /*

            const url = 'https://api.emploi-store.fr/partenaire/evenements/v1/salonsenligne';

             

            const url = 'https://books.googleapis.com/books/v1/myconfig/getUserSettings';

                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',

            */

            console.log(token);

            /*
      
let opts = new HttpHeaders();
opts = opts.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);

            console.log(opts);

          
            const opts = {
      
              headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
              })
            };

            */
              
      
             let headers = new HttpHeaders()
              .set('content-type', 'application/json')
              .set('Accept', 'application/json')
              .set('Authorization', 'bearer ' + token);
                    
              const h = headers.keys();
          
            console.log(h);
          
          /*
      
            const params = new HttpParams()
              .set('qualification', '0')
              .set('motsCles', 'informatique')
              .set('commune', '51069,76322,46083,12172,28117');
      
      */
      
            return this.httpClient.get<any>(url, { headers : headers });
}
```

As you can see i tried a lot of things (proxy, differents ways of setting header etc) and nothing worked so far.

I get a correct token (i let my credentials if you wanna try, i can change them afterward) and i think maybe the header with bearer token could be faulty so i tried with other external APIs (google Books) with no problem accessing the API requiring bearer token and the same configuration.

Help pls !

Comment: Maybe you could try to create a copy of your problem at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular) for reproducibility?

Comment: I will give a try when i got the time to do it thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted : i forgot to add some scope when requesting the token (2 scopes for the same api).

The code was good ! :)